# How do I update a database that's in use?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm building a web application using ASP.NET MVC with SQL Server and my development process is going to be like

- Make changes in SQL Server locally
- Create LINQ-to-SQL classes as necessary
- Before committing any change set that has a database, script out the database so that I can regenerate it if I ever need to

What I'm confused about is how I'm going to update the production database which will have live data in set.

For example, let's say I have a table like

```
             People 
========================================
Id | FirstName | LastName    | FatherId
----------------------------------------
 1 | 'Anakin'  | 'Skywalker' | NULL
 2 | 'Luke'    | 'Skywalker' | 1
 3 | 'Leah'    | 'Skywalker' | 1
```

in production and locally and let's say I add an extra column locally

```
ALTER TABLE People ADD COLUMN LightsaberColor VARCHAR(16)
```

and update my LINQ to SQL, script it out, test it with sample data and decide that I want to add that column to production.

As part of a deployment process, how would I do that? Does there exist some tool that could read my database generation file (call it GenerateDb.sql) and figure out that it needs to update the production `People` table to put default values in the new column, like

```
                      People 
 ==========================================================
 Id | FirstName | LastName    | FatherId | LightsaberColor
 ----------------------------------------------------------
  1 | 'Anakin'  | 'Skywalker' | NULL     | NULL
  2 | 'Luke'    | 'Skywalker' | 1        | NULL
  3 | 'Leah'    | 'Skywalker' | 1        | NULL
```

???

Answer (score 1):

You should have a staging DB that is identical to the production database.
When you add any changes to the database, you should perform these changes to the staging DB first, and you can of course compare the dev and staging DB to generate a script with the difference.

Visual Studio has a Schema Compare that generate a script with the differences between a two databases.
There are some other tools a well that does the same.

So, you can generate the script, apply it to the staging Db and if everything went fine, you can apply the script on the production DB

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is right you must have a staging process whenever we commit features we use TFS from Development to Production that is called staging you can look up the history of the TFS whether the database or the solution. and if you're not using TFS in Visual Studio and MSSQL Server.

I guess that your are commiting youre features directly to your server that is your production test. or you can test that in your test server first to see the changes.

Another thing is that I guess if you use stored procedures you can use Temporary Tables if you're asking about the script.

I guess that it's your first time commiting in a live server..